# Function Crashes Main After Finishing Execution - C

Tags: c, crash, program-entry-point

I made this simple program that asks the user to input the number of columns the matrix called `arp` is going to have because, that way when the program asks the user to input a number so it can find matches on the numbers stored at the array without comparing all 10 columns allocated on memory with **array to pointer type**.

The problem here comes when the user inputs into the columns size definition 2. All works fine before the last function of **`p3()`** does its job, then it doesn't even return to main to execute the infinite loop defined there. I have tried removing the pointers and didn't work; I also tried removing other parts of the code but still nothing...

Update: Tried removing the function to find elements `felmnt()` and still the same.

Here is The *Buggy* Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int loop = 1;

void keepalive(void)
{
    int ckr = 0;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\n    ******[s]<< CONTINUE | EXIT >>[n]******\n");
    while(printf("    > ") && (ckr = getchar()) != 's' && ckr != 'n') fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    if(ckr == 'n') loop = 0;
    system("CLS");
}

void felmnt(int *colu, int (*arp)[10])
{
    int nius=0, colmts, x, i, ejct;
    do
    {   // loop to let the user find more elements inside matrix
        colmts=0;
        printf("\n    Insert The Number To Find\n    > ");
        scanf("%d", &nius);
        for(x=0; x<*colu; x++)  // search of element inside matrix
        {
            for(i=0; i<=9; i++)
                if(nius == arp[i][x])
                    colmts++;
        }
        if(colmts>1)  // results printing
        {
            printf("\n    %d Elements Found", colmts);
        }else if(colmts)
        {   
            printf("\n    1 Element Found"); 
        }else 
        {
            printf("\n    Not Found");
        }
        printf("\n    TRY AGAIN? s/n\n    > ");
        ejct=getchar();
        getchar();
    }while(ejct=='s');
}

void mat(int *colu, int (*arp)[10])
{
    int ci, cn, tst=0;
    for(ci=0; ci<*colu; ci++)
    {
        for(cn=0; cn<10; cn++)
        {
            printf("\n    Input The Number [%d][%d]\n    > ", ci+1, cn+1);
            scanf(" %d", &arp[cn][ci]);
        }
    } 
    printf("    Numbers Inside Matrix> ");
    for(ci = 0; ci<*colu; ci++)
    {
        for(cn=0; cn<10; cn++) printf(" %d", arp[cn][ci]);
    }
}

void p3(void)
{       // >>>>main<<<<
    int colu=0;
    while(loop)
    {
        printf("\n    Input The Quantity Of Columns To Use\n    > ");
        scanf("%d", &colu);
        int arp[10][colu];
        mat(&colu, arp);
        felmnt(&colu, arp);
        keepalive();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int ck = 0, ndx;
    while(1)
    {    // infinite loop
        p3();
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nPause !!!");
        getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should keep removing stuff like you did, and then post the minimal remaining code still showing the error here.

Comment: Hint.  Crash is in `felmnt` accessing `arp[0][0]`.  `arp` in `mat` and `felmnt`?  Two different values.

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin);`  per the C standard, this is undefined behavior.  Sadly, visual studio allows it

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `system( "CLS" )`   This is not a portable command to send to the OS.  Windows will recognize it, but most OSs do not.  Suggest using the ANSI escape commands to control the terminal/cursor

Comment: Your array dimensions don't match.  If the user gives `colu` the value 2, then you pass an array `int arp[10][2]` to a function that expects `int (*arp)[10]` — and the two types are quite different, but the compiler can't easily help you.  (GCC 8.2.0 set to fussy doesn't give any useful complaints, for example.)  You allocated 20 integers, but the input code goes on to read many more (I think it reads 100; I got bored after entering 22 numbers). So, whatever else is happening, you're writing out of bounds of the array, and from there, anything is valid since you've invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! just figured out that i confused rows with columns, that's why it wasn't working :-), recommendations saved!

Comment: I've rollback your transformation of the question into a non-question: please find your solution in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53347442/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own.